# I don't know why my calathea makoyana is dying

Tags: houseplants, indoors, roots, rot

I was only traveling for 5 days, when I came back *Calathea* leaves were curled. I thought it was because of the hot weather,  I watered it, but it did not improve. When I thought that there might be a problem in the roots, I noticed that the rhizomes were softening and shrinking. I didn't know what to do I tried to clean the rotting roots, there are still live roots but I don't know what to do please help.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is root rot, the roots are dead and rot. The cause is overwatering, you gave the plant too much water or there is no proper drainage in your pot. I am not sure if you can save this one, if you want to try, remove as much as possible rot away from the roots and put in clean soil with good drainage. Good luck!